# Load HTML Content if possible

Tags: jquery, html

In a page I have a tab of which it contains few select boxes. Each selectbox contains around 40 countries. That's in my HTML 120 x `<option value="countrycode">Country Name</option>`. Is there any way that I could load that HTML content when the tab button is pressed? I was thinking of XML.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cant you just hook in to the onfocus event of the select and you check whether the select has data loaded in it or not, if not make the query to the server and retrieve your option data and remembr to build up the markup on your client side.

```
$("select").focus(function()
{

    if($(this).find("option").length>0)
      return;
    //server call to get your json data i.e the option value use $.get, $.ajax  etc.
    //hook in the callback function to populate the markup

});
```

What do you think?

Comment: Hi there. Sorry for the late reply. It seems a good idea. Is it possible to give me an example of few value's?